# Azure Get Live Queries

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm looking for a query to get the current running queries in Azure SQL.  All of the T-SQL I've found do not show the running queries when I test them (for instance, run a query in one window, then look in another window at the running queries).  Also, I'm not looking for anything related to the time, CPU, etc, but only the actual running query text.

When I run ...

```
SELECT * FROM Table --(takes 2 minutes to load)
```

... and run a standard information query (like from [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/) or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)), I don't see the above query (I assume there's another way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select * from sys.dm_exec_requests should give you what other sessions are doing.You can join this with sys.dm_exec_sql_text to get the text if needed. sys.dm_tran_locks gives the locks hold / waiting. If this is V12 server you can also use dbcc inutbuffer. Make sure that the connection you are running is dbo / server admin

Comment: Is there any way to see log of queries that ran in the past?

Comment: To answer @eddyP23's question in case someone stumbles across this rather old thread: To see a log of queries in Azure SQL you should turn on Audit Logs either on database or server level in the Azure portal. These will log all queries to a storage or other destination. Note that this log grows quickly and can get rather big.